# How to replace $httpProvider in service when I already have defined my $httpProvider

Tags: angularjs

I have factory service:

```
app.factory('sessionInjector', ['sessionService', 'stateService', '$q', function (sessionService, stateService, $q) {
    var myInjectorInstance = { /* ... */ };

    return myInjectorInstance; 
}]);
```

And now I define provider for my module

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector'); 
}]);
```

Now in dialogService want to user angular's $http provider to read html file. 
But I get that exception:

```
Circular dependency found: $http <- dialogService <- sessionService <- sessionInjector <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile
```

**dialogService is used in sessionService.** 
dialogService Looks like this :

```
app.service('sessionService', function ($http, $window, $compile) {
    /* some code */
}
```

Is there way to use $http provider in dialogService without error throwing?

Answer (score 0):

*Is there way to use $http provider in dialogService without error throwing?* **YES**

**HOW**

Instead of injecting `$http` into your `dialogService`, you'll have to inject the injector...which is `$injector`

Then you can execute a function within the injector scope. Like so:

```
$injector.invoke(function ($http) { // <- injecting $http
    // make an http call
});
```

Here's the official documentation: [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a circular dependency like this you can manually inject a dependency using [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) and assign to a variable

```
app.service('sessionService', function ( $window, $compile, $injector) {
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
}
```